# Transverse intersection in a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, compactness, intersection-theory

Is it true that if $M$ is a compact manifold and $X,Y$ are submanifolds of $M$ which intersect transversely that the intersection $X\cap Y$ consists of finitely many points?

I'm trying to understand a proof of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem which, so far as I can tell, makes implicit use of this fact.

My immediate impression is that the answer is yes because otherwise what good is compactness here? I'm trying to prove it by arguing that if there were infinitely many points of intersection then there would be an open cover with no finite subcover and I keep getting stuck. Is there a better way to proceed or is the result simply wrong?

I don't necessarily need a full proof; a yes or no and if yes a push in the right direction would be more than appreciated already.

Comment: Does your definition of transverse intersection require that the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$ have as sum the dimension of $M$? (If so, the answer is yes.)

Comment: Yes and I just realized the proof. Because the dimensions of $X, Y$ are complementary, the (transverse) intersection is zero-dimensional. Then if I also require $X,Y$ to be closed and $X$ to be compact, which both hold in this case, the intersection is also closed. From this I can find a convergent sequence in the subspace topology, but this leads to a contradiction when the distance associated to the topology is considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that satisfies your hypotheses: the 2-manifold $M = S^2 =$ the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the 1-dimensional submanifolds $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \subset S^2$ given by $X = \{(t,0) \,\, | \,\, t \in (0,1)\}$, and $Y = \{(t,\sin(1/t) \,\, | \,\, t \in (0,1)\}$.

Comment: As I understand it, I need to also require both of the submanifolds to be closed and one of them to be compact, correct?

Comment: Yes, that would help greatly.

Comment: Excellent, I think I see what the proof is now, with strengthened hypotheses.

Comment: Note that a closed subspace of a compact space is automatically compact.